# Nodemon starts but the port number is undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

```
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server server.js`
**Server started on PORT: undefined in DEVELOPMENT node.**
```

I tried doing following solution for the above issue but didn't worked:

1. Checked the .env file, everything ok in it.
2. Added dependencies(nodemon, express)
   This is server.js file.

```
const app = require('./app');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
//Setting up config file
dotenv.config({ path: 'backend/config/config.env' })
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on PORT: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} node.`)
})
```

Comment: As I see it, you are specifying a path for dotenv config. Check if the path is valid. Your PORT value from the config.env file is undefined. Perhaps a better way to write the path would be to use "path" core package from node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your dotenv implementation to the following:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

.env file should be located on the same folder as main file where you implement the above code.

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't worked.
.
.
.
`const app = require('./app')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: 'backend/config/config.env'});
app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server started on PORT:${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} node.`);
})`

Comment: @RitikaBajracharya why are you calling `dotenv.config({path: 'backend/config/config.env'}); `?  
Try moving .env file to the same folder of your server.js file and use the dotenv config method like the following. `dotenv.config();`  
Also remember that files should be called **.env**, in your case it should be **.env.config**